# How to re-fire jquery functions after failed validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am building a form using asp MVC3 and MVC Unobtrusive validation.  I noticed some of my jquery functions do not run again after the failed validation.  For example, I have a datepicker on a textbox and a phone number format mask on a textbox, both of which run perfectly the first time time through, but if the form fails validation, they do not 'reload'.

So, I am looking for a way to modify the jquery, so it will run again.  Both the functions are currently 'on document ready' and I'm guessing the page does not reload after the failed validation, which is why they dont work.  For example, here is the phone number mask:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#PersonModel_PhoneNumber").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});
```

and this is the datepicker with added stuff:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PersonModel_DateofBirth").datepicker
            ({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '-100y:c+nn',
                maxDate: '-1d',
                onClose: function ageVerification() {
                    var value = document.getElementById('PersonModel_DateofBirth').value;
                    var birthDate = new Date(document.getElementById('PersonModel_DateofBirth').value);
                    var currDate = new Date();
                    var yearDifferential = currDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();

                    var totalMonths = (yearDifferential * 12) + (currDate.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth());

                    if (value != "") {

                        if (currDate.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()) {
                            totalMonths--;
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        window.alert("Please enter your date of birth");
                    }

                    var age = parseInt(totalMonths / 12);
                    $("#Age").val(age);

                    if (age < 18) {
                        window.alert("You must be 18 or older to use this application.  ");

                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

So I am pretty sure that I need some way of refiring all the jquery functions that I have set to document.ready, maybe change to onclick or something.  Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers, which was to add onclick events.  For example with the datepicker, I put the whole thing in a var, then called it seperatly in a .click. Here is the datepicker:

```
   var verifiedDate = $("#PersonModel_DateofBirth").datepicker
            ({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: '-100y:c+nn',
                maxDate: '-1d',
                onClose: function ageVerification() {
                    var value = $('#PersonModel_DateofBirth').val();
                    var birthDate = new Date($('#PersonModel_DateofBirth').val());
                    var currDate = new Date();
                    var yearDifferential = currDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();

                    var totalMonths = (yearDifferential * 12) + (currDate.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth());

                    if (value != "") {

                        if (currDate.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()) {
                            totalMonths--;
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        window.alert("Please enter your date of birth");
                    }

                    var age = parseInt(totalMonths / 12);
                    $("#Age").val(age);

                    if (age < 18) {
                        window.alert("You must be 18 or older to use this application.  Please use " +
                         "the Student Volunteer application, found here: " +
                         "http://www.salkeiz.k12.or.us/qam/student-criminal-history-check-packet-english");

                    }
                }
            });

            $("#PersonModel_DateofBirth").click(function () {
                verifiedDate.datepicker("show");
        });
```